# javascript, what this condition means? if(display || true){...}

Tags: javascript, boolean, conditional-statements

The `display` variable is optional on the actual function, but I don't understand what it means by `|| true`

What actually checks this condition?  `if(display || true){...}`

```
if(display || true){
$("#container").html(this.displayReport(this.tabData, extraInfo || false));
}
```

Comment: that condition will always be true, so it will always run

Comment: so why the hell would someone put this kind of condition instead of running the code inside of it?

Comment: @GigiIonel We won't know it unless you post more code.

Comment: Either it's part of some debug code, or they thought it's the coalesce operator. It isn't. It used to be used this way, though.

Answer (score 2):

The || is a logical **or** operation, which means that display **or** true will always be true.

Your code actually means `if(true) {...}`, and the if is quite redundant.

Comment: I know very well what || means, but this is what I was thinking about, that is quite redundant

Comment: Sorry - it wasn't obvious from the question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(display || true)
```

This conditional statement checks whether the value of display is true. If it is, the statement is automatically true. If display is false, the second condition is checked.

For an or condition to be true, only one of the statements has to be true.

In this case, the code will always return true because one of the statements is true.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect use of `||` as a coalescing operator. As already noted, this will always return `true`. However, imagine that `display` is a string, instead of a boolean. In that case

```
var result = display || "(none");
```

will either return `display`, or if `display` isn't set, `"(none)"`.

This exploits the fact that in Javascript, both `undefined` and `null` evaluates to `false`. That means that when the value is unassigned, you can use `||` to return the "backup" value instead - the left operand is false, so the result of the evaluation is the right value, no matter what.

Whoever wrote your code sample probably copied this over from some older code or some javascript cookbook, without understanding how it actually works, and why it will not work in your case. The critical thing to realize here is that values like `false` or `0` *also* evaluate to `false` - so in your case, you will indeed always get `true`.

Note that the `extraInfo || false` *will* work as expected. It's just the `true` that's giving you trouble. To fix this, simply use

```
 if (!(display === false))
```

If display is undefined, the type-sensitive comparison will return false, and thus you get the default `true`. Otherwise, if display is `true`, you again get `true`, and if display is `false`, you get `!true`, i.e. `false`.

Comment: It's not about trouble, It's about that it`s redundant as Ori Drori said...anyway, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @GigiIonel It's not redundant! It's incorrect. The original intent was obviously to allow a default value of `true` - but that's not what it actually *does*. See my update for a fix that handles the default value properly (while being quite annoying to read, admittedly).

Answer (score 1):

try to change,

```
if(display || true){
$("#container").html(this.displayReport(this.tabData, extraInfo || false));
}
```

to

```
if(true){
$("#container").html(this.displayReport(this.tabData, extraInfo || false));
}
```